# ifeq solaris make

Tags: makefile

I'm using the following makefile code that works on GNU/Linux:

```
var0="abc"

ifeq ($(var0),"abc")
var1=alpha
else
var1=beta
endif

all:
    @echo $(var1)
```

But on Solaris, it produces an error "unexpected line end" or something to that effect.  How can I get the desired behavior on Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

Which make are you using on Solaris?

It would probably be easier to use Gnu make on Solaris rather than to make your makefile work with different makes

Comment: Solaris does not have any if or equivalent I think http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5165/make-1s?a=view

So I used to end up doing more in shell commands

Comment: Does your build environment really not support gmake? As of S10, it's installed by default, isn't it?